# Upload multiple files with wpf progress bars

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

i´am looking for a solution in C# and WPF.
I try to upload multiple files to a server. Every upload should be shown in the listbox within a progressbar.

I have a WPF listbox template with a progress bar and a textblock in it:

```
<ListBox Name="lbUploadList" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" Margin="530,201.4,14.2,33.6" Grid.Row="1">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid Margin="0,2">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding File}" />
                <ProgressBar Grid.Column="1" Minimum="0" Maximum="100" Value="{Binding Percent}" />
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>


public class UploadProgress
{
    public string File { get; set; }
    public int Percent { get; set; }
}

List<UploadProgress> uploads = new List<UploadProgress>();
uploads.Add(new UploadProgress() { File = "File.exe", Percent = 13 });
uploads.Add(new UploadProgress() { File = "test2.txt", Percent = 0 });
lbUploadList.ItemsSource = uploads;
```

How can i update a progress bar in this list?

Can somebody help me to find the correct solution? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly you will need to implement [`INotfyPropertyChanged` interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx) on your class. Then you should be in a position to bind the progress bar value to the ViewModel like so:

```
public class UploadProgress : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    // This method is called by the Set accessor of each property. 
    // The CallerMemberName attribute that is applied to the optional propertyName 
    // parameter causes the property name of the caller to be substituted as an argument. 
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    private int percent = 0;
    public int Percent 
    {
        get { return percent; }
        set
        {
            if (value != percent)
            {
                percent = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Note that you need .NET-Framework 4.5 our above to use `CallerMemberName`.

Answer (score 0):

Your UploadProgress-class has to implement [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/126249/MVVM-Pattern-in-WPF-A-Simple-Tutorial-for-Absolute#premain5), to notify the binding when it's value changes.

Now you just have to change the Percent-value of some UploadProgress-instance in your list to change the corresponding ProgressBars value.

Maybe you create a method which sets the Percentage value, like:

```
private void Upload(UploadProgress upload)
{
    byte[] uploadBytes = File.GetBytes(upload.File);
    step = 100/uploadBytes.Length;
    foreach (byte b in uploadBytes)
    {
         UploadByte(b);
         upload.Percent += step; //after you implemented INotifyPropertyChanged correctly this line will automatically update it's prograssbar.
    }
}
```

I really don't know how a upload works in detail, so this method is just to show you how you could handle the percentage value.